# Fermat numbers of the form of $b^2$

Tags: number-theory

For n > 1 Let $F_n = 2^{2^n} + 1$ be a fermat number and b = $2^{2^{n - 2}}$ * ($2^{2^{n - 1}}$ - 1 ).

Then $b^2$ $\equiv$ 2 (mod $F_n$)

I tried to square the original expression I got something ugly that I couldn't simplify further.

I got $b^2$ = $2^{2^{n - 1}}$ * ($2^{2^n}$ - $2 * 2^{2^{n - 1}}$ + 1) $\equiv$ - ($2 * 2^{2^n} * 2^{2^{n-1}}$) (mod $F_n$). I stopped here I can't simplify it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! Just notice that $2^{2^n}\equiv -1\pmod{2^{2^n}+1}$ :

$$\begin{align}b^2&=2^{2^{n-1}}(2^{2^n}-2*2^{2^{n-1}}+1)\\&=2^{2^{n-1}}(2^{2^n}+1-2*2^{2^{n-1}})\\&\equiv2^{2^{n-1}}(0-2*2^{2^{n-1}})\pmod{2^{2^n}+1}\\&\equiv-2*2^{2^{n-1}}*2^{2^{n-1}}\pmod{2^{2^n}+1}\\&\equiv-2*2^{2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}}\pmod{2^{2^n}+1}\\&\equiv-2*2^{2^n}\pmod{2^{2^n}+1}\\&\equiv -2*(-1)\pmod{2^{2^n}+1}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your simplification isn't working out. Let's go with the first expression for $b^2$

$2^{2^n}$ mod $F_n$ = -1

so, (all mod $F_n$) $b^2$ = -$2^{2^{n-1}}$*$2^{2^{n-1}+1}$ = -$2^{2^n +1}$ = -$2$ ($2^{2^n}$) = -($2$)($-1$) mod $F_n$ = $2$ mod $F_n$